# How to PXE boot of Raspberry PI along with other computers?

Tags: raspberry-pi, dhcp, arm, pxe, syslinux

I have a LAN with PXE boot configured. Any PC computer if configured, presents me with PXE DHCP information, then netboots and presents me with pxelinux menu.

If I remove SD card from my Raspberry PI and turn it on, nothing happens, display (HDMI) shows nothing.

Should I see something in the case?

As I understand, what I boot is `pxelinux.0` which is binary incompatible with `ARM`? How can I distinguish netboot by MAC address? As I understand, `pxelinux.cfg` distinguishing by MAC is `pxelinlux` thing and won't work?

Suppose I decide to switch to netboot of Raspberry PI completely, should I just specify `myraspberrypiimage.img` instead of `pxelinux.0` in my `DHCP` config?